# Google recapcha version 1

Tags: angularjs, recaptcha

Am trying to use the old version of google recaptcha,
And my application is in angular.

When i use this in the child pages of the application,recaptcha is not displaying(Warning is showing :

> **Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write
>   into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless
>   it is explicitly opened.**,

but when i use the same code in the master page or my layout page it is working.

This is my code used to display captcha:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=KEY_"> </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

For adding captcha on a website most peopls use Google reCaptcha. You can create the captcha with help of [Google reCaptcha API](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list).

[reCaptcha Documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/start)

The Google API uses Ajax req. and res. for verifying the user response we want to create the AJAX response.